# Strange Cygwin terminal behaviour with trap and stty -echo

Tags: bash, cygwin, read, stty

If I exit the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> during the `read ...` command, the `stty -echo` mode is stuck!
(I'm using the Cygwin terminal on Windows 10.)

Unfortunately `read -s` won't solve my problem as it is "slow" to react if it's called in a loop. (Some of the input may be visible.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'stty echo && exit' SIGINT
stty -echo
read -n 1 input # pressing Ctrl+C here!!
# ...
```

However if I leave `-n 1` works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'stty echo && exit' SIGINT
stty -echo
read input # pressing Ctrl+C here!!
# ...
```

This also works as expected for some reason:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts k flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
  k) do_read="true" ;;
  esac
done

if [[ $do_read != "true" ]]; then
  # just restarting
  "$0" -k && stty echo
  exit
fi

trap 'echo exiting && exit' SIGINT
stty -echo
read -n 1 input # pressing Ctrl+C here!!
# ...
```

Could anyone please explain what's going on?

Comment: It happens that bash's buggy. A workaround which works in bash on Linux is replacing the first trap with `trap 'stty echo' EXIT`. Bash (but not other shells) will also run an `EXIT` trap upon terminating because of a signal.

Comment: @UncleBilly It works as expected with `EXIT`. :o (One thing I forgot to mention is that the trap also gets executed with the `SIGINT` version, just buggy. So if I write an echo there it works.)

Comment: Not sure if you were hoping for more input...if so you might want to remove the cygwin tag and its reference in the subject given that it's a general bash issue.